# The condition in oracle sql don't work fine because sometimes is null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following issue. I thought that the query was correctly created but I have just verified that sometimes the results do not correspond with reality. I have seen through the tables that the nodeassociation table sometimes has no data, so

```
AND j.id = na.source_node_id
AND na.sink_node_entity = 'Component'
AND na.source_node_entity = 'Issue'
AND na.sink_node_id = c.id
```

It would not be true and I would not pick up this data (w.timeworked if it exists). What I would like in these cases would be to crarme a c.cname of name 'Empty' and add in this cname all w.timeworked where there is no data in nodeassociation. Any solution to someone? Next I put the sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname                                              AS component, 
                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER ()                     AS sum_tipo, 

                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER (partition BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component 
FROM            jira.jiraissue j, 
                jira.worklog w, 
                jira.project p, 
                jira.issuetype t, 
                jira.component c, 
                (SELECT source_node_id, source_node_entity,sink_node_entity
                       ,max(sink_node_id) as sink_node_id
                    FROM jira.nodeassociation
                  GROUP BY source_node_id, source_node_entity,sink_node_entity) na, 
                jira.cwd_user u

WHERE           w.issueid=j.id 
AND             j.project=p.id 
AND             j.id= na.source_node_id 
AND             na.sink_node_entity = 'Component' 
AND             na.source_node_entity = 'Issue'
AND             na.sink_node_id=c.id 
AND             t.id=j.issuetype 
And             w.author= u.lower_user_name
AND             w.author in ( select distinct author from jira.worklog where author in (select distinct lower_user_name from jira.cwd_user where display_name in (${Autor})))   
AND             p.pname=  ${Proyecto}
AND             t.pname=${Tipo}
AND             to_char(w.startdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') >=${FromDate}
AND             to_char(w.startdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') <=${ToDate}
```

The ${} is the form to pass a parameters in the aplication that i'm working

Comment: It sounds like you want left a outer join to that table, or to the inline view/subquery (`na`). I'd suggest you change to modern join syntax before you try to change the join types though.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexPoole says a current `JOIN` syntax should work well to perform an outer join. I modified your query a little bit to use this syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname                                              AS component, 
                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER ()                     AS sum_tipo, 

                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER (partition BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component 
FROM            jira.jiraissue j, 
                jira.worklog w, 
                jira.project p, 
                jira.issuetype t, 
                jira.component c,
                jira.cwd_user u
LEFT JOIN       (SELECT source_node_id, source_node_entity,sink_node_entity
                       ,max(sink_node_id) as sink_node_id
                    FROM jira.nodeassociation
                  GROUP BY source_node_id, source_node_entity,sink_node_entity) na 
             ON j.id= na.source_node_id 
            AND na.sink_node_entity = 'Component' 
            AND na.source_node_entity = 'Issue'
            AND na.sink_node_id=c.id 
WHERE           w.issueid=j.id 
AND             j.project=p.id 
AND             t.id=j.issuetype 
And             w.author= u.lower_user_name
AND             w.author in ( select distinct author from jira.worklog where author in (select distinct lower_user_name from jira.cwd_user where display_name in (${Autor})))   
AND             p.pname=  ${Proyecto}
AND             t.pname=${Tipo}
AND             to_char(w.startdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') >=${FromDate}
AND             to_char(w.startdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') <=${ToDate}
```

I suggest you update the other joins to current syntax too. This way it'll look cleaner since the `WHERE` clause will only include filters and no join conditions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer join. You can do it with your current old-style syntax, which I don't recommend, just change these lines:

```
AND             j.id= na.source_node_id (+)
AND             na.sink_node_entity (+) = 'Component' 
AND             na.source_node_entity (+) = 'Issue'
AND             c.id = nvl(na.sink_node_id, (select id from jira.component where cname = 'Empty'))
```

In the last line, when `na` is null, it'll pick the `jira.component` row with a `c.cname` of 'Empty', like you said. I'm assuming it already exists.

Or you could rewrite your whole query to use ANSI syntax.

Edit: modified to display "Empty" as the component name instead of null.

```
SELECT DISTINCT nvl(c.cname, 'Empty')                                              AS component, 
                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER ()                     AS sum_tipo, 

                Sum(w.timeworked / 3600) OVER (partition BY c.cname) AS sum_by_component 
FROM            jira.jiraissue j
INNER JOIN jira.worklog w
    ON w.issueid=j.id 
INNER JOIN jira.project p
    ON j.project=p.id
    AND p.pname=  ${Proyecto}
INNER JOIN jira.issuetype t
    ON t.id=j.issuetype
    AND t.pname=${Tipo}
INNER JOIN jira.cwd_user u
    ON w.author= u.lower_user_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT source_node_id, source_node_entity,sink_node_entity
                       ,max(sink_node_id) as sink_node_id
                    FROM jira.nodeassociation
                  GROUP BY source_node_id, source_node_entity,sink_node_entity) na
    ON j.id= na.source_node_id 
    AND na.sink_node_entity = 'Component' 
    AND na.source_node_entity = 'Issue'
LEFT OUTER JOIN jira.component c
    ON  c.id = na.sink_node_id
WHERE           w.author in ( select distinct author from jira.worklog where author in (select distinct lower_user_name from jira.cwd_user where display_name in (${Autor})))   
AND             to_char(w.startdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') >=${FromDate}
AND             to_char(w.startdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') <=${ToDate}
```

Comment: empty component doesn't exist. how can i create it? in the sql no in tables?

Comment: @ilanas - You could insert a row for it in the `jira.component` table, but you can also just pretend it exists. I'll edit my answer.